# Sprites disappear after touch instead of after drag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In the game I'm trying to develop currently, I am trying to drag and drop sprites. This is my current code:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
//gameStat is a boolean I use for pause and play function
if(gameStat == TRUE)
{
    NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

    //Swipe Detection - Beginning point
    beginTouch = location;
    touchflag = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < [sprArray count]; i++)
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[sprArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
        {
            selectedSprite = sprite;
            //touchflag is an int, if its 1, it will move the sprite
            //spriteTouch is a boolean for checking if the sprite's been moved
            touchflag = 1;
            _spriteTouch = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
}}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(gameStat == TRUE)
{
    NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

    if(_spriteTouch == TRUE)
    {
        if(touchflag == 1)
        {
            //Should move the sprite from start location x and y to end location x and y
            selectedSprite.position = ccp(location.x, location.y);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < [sprArray count]; i++)
            {
                CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[sprArray objectAtIndex:i];
                if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
                {
                    selectedSprite = sprite;
                    touchflag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(gameStat == TRUE)
{
    //End point of sprite after dragged
    NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

    endTouch = location;
    posX = endTouch.x;

    //Minimum swipe length
    posY = ccpDistance(beginTouch, endTouch);

    if(_spriteTouch == TRUE)
    {
        if(selectedSprite != nil)
        {
            if(selectedSprite.tag == 1)
            {
                [self gameOver];
            }
            else if(selectedSprite.tag == 2)
            {
                if(countDown > 0)
                {
                    [self ClearGame];
                }
                else if(countDown == 0)
                {
                    [self gameOver];
                }
            }
        }
        selectedSprite = nil;
    }
    _spriteTouch = FALSE;
}}
```

The drag and drop of the sprite works okay. My problem is that the game goes into the method either gameOver or ClearGame even if you just touch the sprite. I need to tell my code not to do anything unless the sprite is dragged but I can't figure out how to do it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check, and calculate position displacement for then put condition on displaced value.

Comment: So if I read you correct you want the game to clear whenever the sprite is dragged, but at the moment it ends whenever the sprite is touched?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it happens right now. I have a hunch that the my methods are all jumbled out but I can't figure out in which order I should make them since if I put the drag method inside the touches moved method, the game doesn't end if you don't drag it but when you do, you won't see the sprite move. It just says that the game's cleared.

Comment: If not that, I suspect that my selectedSprite.position = ccp(....) is the cause of the problem but if I try to remove it, or replace it with the drag method, I get a bad access exception

Comment: @rptwsthi, I'm not sure I understand your suggestion sorry.

Comment: Actually, never mind, I figured out how to fix it. Thank you for your time and suggestions. :) I'll post my answer just in case someone else encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I kind of solved my problem after messing around with my code a little. It was indeed because my code was jumbled. So here's how it looks now:

```
//I declared a boolean called _spriteTouch at the top of my class
-(id)init
{
//Added this to my init method
_spriteTouch = FALSE;}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(gameStat == TRUE)
{
NSSet *allTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [[allTouch allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

if(touchflag == 1)
{
//set _spriteTouch to true then set the position of the sprite
_spriteTouch = TRUE;
[selectedSprite setPosition:location];
}}}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(gameStatus == TRUE)
{
    //I removed the NSSet *touch, CGPoint location etc since I no longer need it here. Keep it if you're gonna use it somewhere in this method
    //Check if _spriteTouch is true, if it is then the sprite would do what it should accordingly
    if(_spriteTouch == TRUE)
    {
        if(selectedSprite != nil)
        {
            //do something
        }
        selectedSprite = nil;
    }
    _spriteTouch = FALSE;
}
```

}

So that's pretty much it. I also removed the endTouch, beginTouch, dragSprite, etc since I didn't have any need for them anymore. I hope this helps someone else.